# Would PHPLint's advice be beneficial to our community?

Tags: coding-standards

I recently found this static PHP code analyzer called [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/). One of the things it can do, is look at code like this:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
function getText() {
  return 5;
}
```

And complain that a 5, is not a string. It seems to me like this could potentially reduce bugs, and perhaps even security issues in our code. One nice thing is that I see it could give is that for return values from function, all you ever need to check is (=== null). If it's not null, then you have the data you expected.

At the surface, this seems like a possibly great addition to our codebases, core and contrib alike. But perhaps there are problems with this that I don't see?

I started applying appropriate doc-blocks to own of my own modules, and one of the issue I hit myself is that because core frequently uses arrays with mixed data in them, there are limits to what kinds of checks PHPLint can do, which causes a lot of warnings.

**Edit:** One concrete example of an issue that this could prevent is [this notice from php 5.4](https://drupal.org/node/1338282). This code has *always* failed, it's just that no one noticed until PHP 5.4 made the implicit casting a notice. In this case the bug is relatively harmless, but more subtle errors and security problems could creep in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, there sure are benefits. There are however some issues with doing it, as you partially found out yourself already.

- There will be like a million false warnings, might just be as hard to find the real issues as when simply reading the code.
- Drupal has a quite a few custom coding standards. For example, we're currently not using type declarations in docblocks except for @return $class.

I don't know how configurable PHPLint is, maybe there are a few checks that would make sense to run on our code.

For coding style issues, it might make more sense to use http://drupal.org/project/drupalcs

Comment: So initially there would be a million false positives yes, but what if a) a future version of Drupal mandated this and b) support for a "list of ignores file" support was added?